# Extension method with ref does not work with arrays

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I wrote this code:

```cs
public static T[][] Populate<T>(this ref T[][] arg, T with) where T : struct
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arg[i].Length; j++)
        {
            arg[i][j] = with;
        }
    }
    return arg;
}
```

And I get the following error:

[image: error]
Why doesn't this work? A similar situation would work when `this` is taken away, no? And the restrictions seem to be met: I specified `T` must be a `struct`; I understand that `arg` is really an array, but what difference does that make? Is it that the array passes by reference by default, so it is invalid?

Are there any equivalent statements that I could write that wouldn't produce errors?

Phew, sorry for all of the questions. Thanks.

Comment: An array isn't a struct, even if its members are.

Comment: "Is it that the array passes by reference by default" Arrays, just like all types, are passed by value by default.  Types are only passed by reference when explicitly using `ref`, `in`, or `out`.  The value passed is simply itself a reference for reference types like arrays.  But whether it's passed by value or reference is irrelevant to you since you're not changing the variable, you're only using its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ref` must be specified both in the method declaration and when it is called.

If the `this` argument of the extension could be passed by reference, there wouldn't be any way to specify it when calling the method.

```
someObject.CallSomeExtensionMethod();
```

Where would we put `ref`? There is nowhere.

If we could pass a value by reference without *knowing* that we're passing it by reference, weird things could happen. It's normal to call an extension method that modifies the value passed as the first argument. For example, we could write an extension method to shuffle a list:

```
list.Shuffle();
```

We expect the list to be modified. But imagine our surprise if the extension method actually caused `list` to point to an entirely different instance of `List`. Even if we knew it was happening that would be weird, but if that behavior wasn't explicit it would be chaos. We could call an extension that isn't `ref` and someone could change it to be `ref` without breaking anything, introducing all sorts of crazy, unpredictable effects.

Having `ref` in both the method and where it's used is like a contract - that method is telling us that it may replace our reference, and we're giving it explicit permission.

Answer (score 1):

It's because arrays are reference types.
So what you have is a reference to an array containing other references to arrays containing structs. Just because the content of the array is a struct doesn't mean the array itself is.

You don't need to use ref when passing arrays (**as long as you're only changing the contents and not the reference**) because, as already stated, they are reference-types. This means this function should have the exact behaviour you want if you simply remove the ref keyword.

Now I believe this should help you on how to fix your error. However I didn't include why you cannot use ref for extension-methods and in the meantime [a really good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485531/10883465) already got posted, so go check that out too :)

**Edit:**
Just something I wanted to add. You don't really need to return the array again because all you do is change things **inside** it (after all, it's only a reference so these changes go through without you having to return the array again).

You would want to return it if you either:

a. Change the reference in the current scope and aren't using a ref keyword
 b. You want to string calls together even though you're using a reference type to create a bit of syntactic sugar (syntax like `app.UseX().UseY().UseZ()`).

Comment: "You don't need to use ref when passing arrays" Not in the code shown.  If you want to be able to actually change the variable, or if it would be important to observe changes to the variable after the method has been called, and not just access the array provided without expecting it to change mid-invocation, then you'd need to use a reference parameter.

Comment: This also doesn't actually answer the question of why extension methods cannot have ref parameters for the first parameter.

Comment: How would you use a ref keyword here then? Also the method OP has created is very basic and doesn't require the ref keyword because they're working with arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that initializing the `arg` array within another extension method wouldn't be possible?

Comment: I think I don't fully understand what you mean by that, sorry. As your code will show you, there's no issue with populating the array if you don't use the ref keyword. The only thing you cannot do is assign a new array to the arg. Well you can but it will only change the reference in the current method and not the one that got initially passed in.

Comment: @Joelius Like I said, it's not needed *in the code shown*.  You said it's not needed on arrays ever, and that's just wrong.

Comment: @Servy I see what you mean. I'm of course talking about changing things inside the array as OP does in the shown function. If you change the reference it's something different but I believe those are the basics about value- and reference types and I don't know how much of it I have to explain.

Comment: @Servy I have edited my answer. Does this approach clear the potential missunderstanding?

Comment: @Joelius Yeah, I'm chaining method calls. Also, what I meant by my earlier comment is assign `arg` to a `new T[][]` but now I know that that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay yes then returning it absolutely makes sense. And yes, that doesn't work and I'm glad you understood why. Thanks @Scott Hannen for explaining it well.

Comment: Thank you as well!